# Flask url_for could not build endpoint based on working code. Asks if I want index?

Tags: flask, jinja2

My Flask app already serves up several pages. I just made `channels.html`. For a route, I copied down and changed `/messages`, which already works. I then tried adding a link from `messages.html` to `channels.html`, but received the error:  `Could not build url for endpoint 'channels'. Did you mean 'index' instead?` The error references the line `<a href="{{ url_for('channels') }}">Channels</a>` in `messages.html`. I checked spelling, syntax, decorator placement, and duplicative names; everything looks ok. Plus, the new code was built off of code that was previously tested.

So, why the error?

```
@app.route('/channels', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def channels():
    return render_template("channels.html")

@app.route('/messages', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def messages():
    return render_template("messages.html")
```

**messages.html (top part)**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"  style="min-height: 100vh">
        <div class="col-md-3 border border-danger rounded">
            <div class="row mt-2 justify-content-start">
                Header
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="row mt-2 justify-content-start" id="channelHeader">
                Channels
            </div>-->
            <div class="row mt-2 justify-content-start" id="channels">
                <a href="{{ url_for('channels') }}">Channels</a>
            </div>
            &nbsp;
            <div class="row justify-content-start" id="dmsg">
                Direct Messages
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 border border-danger rounded">
{% endblock %}
```

**channels.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="display-3">
        <strong>Create A Channel</strong>
    </div>

    <form action="{{ url_for('channels') }}" id="channelForm" class="mt-4">
        <!-- Will need check for duplicate email -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="channelName">Channel Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="channelName" aria-describedby="channelName" placeholder="Enter Channel Name">
      </div>
      <!-- Will need check for duplicate username -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inviteUsers">Invite Other Users (optional)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inviteUsers" aria-describedby="inviteUsers" placeholder="Search by name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="purpose">Purpose</label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="purpose" rows="3" placeholder="Purpose">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: any chance you defined the "channels" view function more than once? Or any other functions with that name?

Comment: Nope. Just double checked.

Comment: are you able to share more of your code?

Comment: Just tried creating the link without url_for and got "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." So, it can't see my template in the templates directory???

Comment: Sure. What would you like to see?

Comment: Any parts that you can share. If it's public and on github, I've got some time I can look through it. Based on your URL not found comment though, are you hosting somewhere and haven't fully committed your changes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179486/discussion-between-ryan-and-nick-dima).

Comment: Are u using blueprints?

Comment: @DarkSuniuM What's a blueprint?

Comment: You can create simple and small apps, named blueprint, connect them to your main app